# Magento 2: Why di compile is not 100%?

Tags: magento2, di, compiler, setup-di-compile

When we run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**Why all are not will be 100% & 7/7?**

```
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 48.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 48.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]
  0% 1 sec 48.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 secs 51.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 secs 51.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 2 mins 224.2 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 2 mins 224.2 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 2 mins 224.8 MiB
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 2 mins 224.8 MiB
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 3 mins 244.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 3 mins 244.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 4 mins 279.5 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 4 mins 279.5 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 5 mins 332.2 MiB
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 5 mins 332.2 MiB
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 6 mins 297.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

If it's 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, etc.. then what exactly it's checking/compiling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per my understanding.

> The whole process of **setup:di:compile** is divided into the  7(100%)
>   sub code generations process.

1. Proxies(1/7)
2. Repositories(2/7)
3. Service(3/7)
4. Application(4/7)
5. Interceptors(5/7)
6. Area Configuration(6/7)
7. Interception(7/7)

Each process shows its Compilation part(ex - 1/7) and its percentage(ex - 10%/100%).

When single process end , then next process starting points is ending of previous process.

> **example :**
>
> Proxies Code Generation - this is the 1 process of 7 generations so it
>   will end on 1/7(14%)
>
> Now Second Process which is Repositories Code Generation - this is
>   starting from 1(14%) and Ended on 2(28%)
>
> Now Third Process which is Service data attributes generation - this
>   is starting from 2(28%) and Ended on (42%)
>
> Same way till 7th process which is Interception cache generation - this is starting from 6(85%) and Ended on 7(100%)
>   Thats why all are not 100%

Hope it makes sense.